# sum of two numbers eqal which is given user input

Tags: arrays

I have an array of 10 items:

```
int [] arrayNum = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

When user input value from console like number 10:

> Please Enter Number : 10

I'd like to find those numbers which sum is `10` (first number pair)

In above array I should get 4 & 6.

Please give me best solution any one have.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. This is not a place to input requirements and get programs implemented. Please show what you have tried, what works and where the problem is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code without showing effort.

Comment: Why 4+6? Why not 1+9?

Comment: I can almost smell what language it is, but always specify it using the tags to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo-code you can start with to find a couple of numbers adding up to a desired target:

```
array[] = {1 .. 10}
desired_value = 12     # will give 2 and 10, from 1 .. 10

for index1 in 1 .. array.size() - 1:
    for index2 in index1 + 1 .. array.size():
        if array[index1] + array[index2] == desired_value:
            print array[index1], array[index2]
            stop program
print "No pairs found"
```

This assumes one-based array indexes and will give you the first pair with the "leftmost" (earliest in the array) initial number.

Converting that to whatever *actual* language you have to use is a job I leave to you because:

- you didn't specify a language;
- you will become a better coder if your practise, practise, practise; and
- it may well be classwork, in which case you should do it yourself and learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is operate with **INVARIANTS** and it also reported the reasoning in the ***EPI*** book (*Elements of Programming Interviews*).

Anyway, the best solution (*complexity **O(n)***) to find **the first pair** (if exists) is to have two pointers and then (in Java for example):

```
int i = 0, j = array.length-1;
do {
    int sum = array[i] + array[j];
    if(sum == k) {
        System.out.println("Number are: " + array[i] + " and " + array[j]);
        break;
    }

    if(sum < k) i++;
    else j--;

} while (i <= j);
```

Comment: You may want to mention that assumes a sorted array.

Comment: sure. He write a sorted array before so i assumed this. Anyway he has to sort the array to use this algorithm.